# IndoorAtlas SDK 2.0 : the position of the blue dote does not want to change

Tags: java, android, indoor-positioning-system

When i tried the indoor atlas API 2.0 it can fetch the image but once the blue dote appear it did not change it's position the only thing i changed in the code is put the API key and secrete key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting locations from IndoorAtlas service requires that you are in a location that has magnetic map created and uploaded to IndoorAtlas cloud. You can do this yourself using a mapping application which you can download from Play (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.indooratlas.mapcreator.main). I would recommend reading this blog article before starting mapping: http://blog.indooratlas.com/2015/06/17/getting-started-with-the-blue-dot/.

Once you have uploaded your magnetic map into IndoorAtlas cloud, you should start receiving location updates from SDK.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not provided any code snippet here what I would suggest you is to go to this SDK 2.0 github project which was put by the IndoorAtlas dev team: https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples/tree/master/Basic/src/main/java/com/indooratlas/android/sdk/examples/imageview and see both Java classes to identify what is missing in your project. You can also check the SDK 2.0 documentation from here: http://docs.indooratlas.com/android/.

Comment: Also, first make sure that you are getting position updates by logging out the locations from `IALocationListener#onLocationChanged` -method.